# Hidden files missing from my phone

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

Some of my pics and videos have been hidden by [NQVAULT](http://www.nq.com/vault). When my phone memory was full, I cleared cache files from system menu. After that my hidden files are missing from phone. Is there any way to get them back?

I tried different software in Windows 8.1 but nothing working. It's showing connection mode mtp/otp doesn't support. After that I rooted my Android. Then also nothing happening..

Samsung Galaxy dous7582

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! While waiting for good answers, you might wish to check with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info). With some luck, one of the hints from there already helps you out. It might also help us if you could provide a link for "NQVAULT": I cannot find that app on Play.